`DocumentNotFoundError` in the `findOne` method in `node-ottoman` (Couchbase ORM)
We use Ottoman as an ORM in our project,
When we use the findOne method, and the item is not found on the server, it responds with a DocumentNotFoundError even though we have set the enforceRefCheck property to true. This property is intended to enforce reference checks, but it seems ignored.

My first question is, Why does it ignore enforceRefCheck?
How can we ignore this error in the 2.4.0 version?
We don't need to throw an error when a document is not found on the server.

According to the documentation, it should return null. I opened a ticket. https://github.com/couchbaselabs/node-ottoman/issues/785
https://ottomanjs.com/docs/basic/model
User.findOne({ name: 'Jane' });
// will return a document with a User with the name "Jane" or null in case of not finding it

I'm not familiar with 'enforceRefCheck'

Thanks. My colleague already opened an issue.
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/node-ottoman/issues/783
